# Mockito - mock subclass method call

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am working with legacy code and trying to write a unit test for an implementation I did. I have the following structure:

```
   AbstractClass:
    ----------------

    public AbstractClass {

    abstract method2();

     void method1(){   
      ...does something...
      ..calls --> method2()
     }
    }

    Subclass
    ------------
    public Subclass extends AbstractClass(){

     void method2(){
      ..do something....
      ..mockThisMethod()...

       return true;   
     }
 }
```

I have an abstract class which has some logic implemented in a specific method.
This method calls than another method implemented in the subclass. The method in the subclass calls other methods which I want to mock.

Is this possible without changing the implementation code (hard to change)?
Mos of the results are suggesting using mockito spying but it doesn't work.

I followed the TestDesign describer here:

https://www.tildedave.com/2011/03/06/pattern-stubbing-legacy-superclasses-with-mockito-spies.html

### What I did is:

```
 Subclass subclass= spy(Subclass.class);
 when(subclass.mockThisMethod()).thenReturn(something);
 subclass.method1() (I am not sure if this line is correct?)
```

So what I want to avoid is, calling the method (`mockThisMethod`) in the `Subclass`.
Since this method does some db-stuff an so on. I know it would be easier to test, if I use object composition instead of inheritance but at this point, it is hard to change the whole implementation. The code above is not working..I get a NPE.

Comment: What is the definition of `mockThisMethod`? Also, I suspect Mockito's `spy` only works when you call methods on the spy reference. Calling methods on `this` is not covered.

Comment: What it means it does not work? Is there any error?

Comment: The `spy` is basically a proxy. If you're not making the call through the reference returned from `spy()`, it does not intercept the call. When you call via `this` reference, you're not calling through the spy.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Mocking a method in the same class you're testing might be a code smell. Also, the intent of your test is not clear. Depending on what you really want to verify, there are other strategies for subclasses.

Comment: I edited my question - added more information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1)** You do not create a Spy by passing the class to the static `Mockito.spy` method.
Instead, you must pass an instance of that particular class:

```
Subclass subclassSpy = spy(new Subclass());
```

Also, consider using annotations:

```
@Spy
private Subclass subclassSpy = new Sublcass();

@Before
public void init(){
   MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

**2)** Avoid using `when.thenReturn` when stubbing a spy.
Instead, use `doReturn..when..methodCall`:

```
doReturn(something).when(sublcass).mockThisMethod();
```

otherwise you will invoke the actual method while stubbing and this may lead to unwanted behavior and/or exceptions.

Comment: I tried this way but if I call then the real method which calls the method in the subclass. Do I use: subclassSpy.method1()? - because I use this object also in the doReturn method. The solution above, does have any effect at my implementation. The code will be executed as it was no spy.

Comment: yes you invoke subclassSpy.method1() and also stub the subclassSpy using it in the when part. Also you need new Sublcass() when using a Spy annotation.. updated the post